# How to pass tr element( ad banner) in iteration. Parsing using BS4

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse html [page](https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/) just for practice and can't take information further then 11 tr. It is ad banner, and I don't know how to pass it.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def get_html(url):
    return requests.get(url).text


def write_csv(data):
    with open('cmc.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        pass


def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('table').find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    for tr in trs:    # для каждой строки в списке строк
        try:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            position = tds[1].text
            name = tds[2].find_all('p')[0].text
            short_name = tds[2].find_all('p')[1].text
            price = tds[3].find('a').text
            change_by_day = tds[4].find('span').text
            change_by_last_7_days = tds[5].find('span').text
            market_capitalization = ''.join((tds[6].find('p').text).split(','))
            volume_in_currency = ''.join((tds[7].find('p').text).split(','))
            volume_in_cryptocurrency = ''.join((tds[7].find_all('p')[1].text).split(','))
            circulating_offer = (''.join((tds[8].find('p').text).split(',')))
            print(position,
                  name,
                  short_name,
                  price,
                  change_by_day,
                  change_by_last_7_days,
                  market_capitalization,
                  volume_in_currency,
                  volume_in_cryptocurrency,
                  circulating_offer)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        except IndexError:
            continue

def main():
    url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/ru/'
    get_page_data(get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the ad element that I can't pass:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to skip banner? or Are you looking to extract information from banner as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a `class`in that `<tr>` and skip it:

```
tr.has_attr("class")
```